# Find the value of a hard integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the value of:
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{e^x}}{\sqrt{e^x+e^{-x}}} \, dx$$

Comment: $= sinh^{-1}(e)-sinh^{-1}(1) \approx 0.844009$
See: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%28e%5Ex%29%2Fsqrt%28e%5Ex%2Be%5E-x%29+from+0+to+1

Comment: Are you sure the integrand is not $$\frac{\sqrt{e^x}}{\sqrt{e^x}+\sqrt{e^{-x}}}$$? If yes, the use $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee if that were the integral, why not just $u=\exp x/2$ substitution?

Comment: @IgorRivin, then I think the formula I mentioned in the last comment, is more useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making the change of variables $ u = \rm e^{x} $ gives an easier integral

> $$ \int_{1}^{\rm e}\!\frac {1}{\sqrt {u^2+1}}{du}. $$

I think you can finish it now.

Comment: I can't help wondering why you went to so much effort to set "e" in a non-italic font in $\displaystyle\int_1^{\rm e}$ and not in the first line of your answer.  Also why write {{{\rm e}}} when {\rm e} suffices (I actually changed that.)?

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $u = \exp(x)$ gives a standard algebraic integral:
$$\int_1^e \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+1}} d u,$$ which falls to the standard substitution $u = Sinh[v].$